# I have Java Map<String,List<String>> and String var, how to return keys whose values(List) contains String var without using For loops

Tags: java, lambda, collections, java-stream, maps

```
private Set<Integer> keysForValue(Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> map, Integer value) {
    
    Set<Integer> keysSetContainingValue = new HashSet<Integer>();
    
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Set<Integer>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if(entry.getValue().contains(value)) keysSetContainingValue.add(entry.getKey());
    }
    return keysSetContainingValue;
}
```

Comment: The title of your question does not match the code you provided.

Comment: Please update the question properly as it is very difficult to understand what is the ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be slightly better to use `keySet()` for the map instead of `entrySet()` to get rid of redundant mapping:

```java
private Set<Integer> keysForValue(Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> map, Integer value) {    
    return map.keySet()
              .stream() // Stream<Integer> of keys
              .filter(k -> map.get(k).contains(value))
              .collect(Collectors.toSet());

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Despite the fact that your title saying Map<String, List> while at your code, you are using Map<Integer, Set> ...

```java
    return map.entrySet()
              .stream()
              .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().contains(value))
              .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
              .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```